# Xamarin Cross Platform Project - Screen size values received wrong

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, height, width

I have a Maps app that is always bigger than the screen size. I try two optiones, the first one with that code:

```
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
        map = new Map
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = Height,
            WidthRequest = Width,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        ...
        ...
        ...
        var stack = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 0
        };
        stack.Children.Add(map);
        stack.Children.Add(slider);
        stack.Children.Add(segments);
        Content = stack;
}
```

And I have that screen, as you see, the buttons are bigger than the screen:

[image]

Even if the button text is smaller or not, it always have the same size.

The second option is:

```
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
    public static int ScreenHeight { get; set; }
    public static int ScreenWidth { get; set; }

    Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position position;

    Map map;
    public MapPage()
    {
        map = new Map
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = ScreenHeight,
            WidthRequest = ScreenWidth,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        ...
        ...
        ...
        var stack = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 0
        };
        stack.Children.Add(map);
        stack.Children.Add(slider);
        stack.Children.Add(segments);
        Content = stack;
}
```

And in Android and iOS projects I have that code:

Android:

```
MapPage.ScreenHeight = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);     
MapPage.ScreenWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
```

iOS:

```
MapPage.ScreenHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
MapPage.ScreenWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
```

And I see that screen:

[image]

As you see, with the second option I can't see the buttons and the slider.

I try to change the VerticalOptions, or delete it, and it gives the same result. Also, I try to add the height and width request to the "stack", just for trying new things, and it gives me the same result as before.

Can anyone helps me? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using google map?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin.Forms.Maps